# Getting type error while trying to execute a simple program?

Tags: python-3.6

Hi I am getting TypeError for the following code

```
def fahrenheit(self,T_in_celsius):
""" returns the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit"""
return (T_in_celsius * 9 / 5) + 32

for t in (22.6, 25.8, 27.3, 29.8):
    print(t,":",fahrenheit(t))
```

Exception:

```
print(t,":",fahrenheit(t))  
TypeError: fahrenheit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'T_in_celsius'
```

Values coming to t in the print():
22.6 :
25.8 :
27.3 :
29.8 :

Comment: why don't you just remove `self` from the function parameters?

Comment: Actually, the question is why did you believe it was a good idea to *add* that `self`?

Comment: Your function is empty, you cannot have an empty function. Use `pass` if you don't want anything inside your function

Comment: you should remove *self* from your function argument if this is not a class method.

Comment: The problem is with Eclipse IDE with pydev plugin, because when I am creating any method it is telling me self should be the first parameter. So now I am started using pycharm. But thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing a (class) method with a (static) function here.
Class methods (Aka functions inside a class that are not annotated with `@staticmethod`) usually have `self` (Or, technically any name, but this is the most common choice) as first argument, which holds a reference to the object this method is called on.

In your case I don't see any classes or objects, so I assume you want to create a (static) function. Just leave out the `self`, since it's only necessary for methods, not for functions.

Comment: Thanks but why it is telling me self must be the first argument in a method?

Comment: @subhashis What exactly is "it"? If you give me some more context, I can try to help you - Otherwise I can only say that METHODS (Non static class functions) require `self` or sth similar to hold an object reference, while (Non-method) FUNCTIONS don't.

Comment: Actually I m new to python basically m a java developer, and so far what I understood that self in python is like this in java. All the methods m creating are non_static methods and not even in any class as we can run any python program without class and main method. But when I am trying to create any method inside eclipse with installed pydev plugin in it it is saying self must be the first parameter in method thats why I placed self. but the solution You provided me worked thanks. By the way is there any difference between function and method(we call function as method in java)

Comment: Java only has methods, since everything in Java is a class (Besides JShell maybe, I'm not an expert on how JShell is compiled internally). Functions only exist in imperative languages, and you can think of them like the equivalent of Java's `static` methods.
And yes, Python's `self` is kinda like Java's `this`, except for the minor detail that `self` is not a reserved word, you could in theory use any variable name for it, as long as you declare it in the method outline.
I don't code with Eclipse, so I can't tell you anything about that, but it sounds like a bug in the plugin to me?